# dns client dies quite often (Ubuntu 22.04LTS, Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ALC6)

Tags: wireless, 22.04, dns, ethernet, client

For some reason the default dns client of my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS installation dies quite often, but still sporadic. I'm sure that it is the dns client, because the command

```
sudo systemctl restart system-resolved
```

fixes my problem for a short amount of time. Even without restarting the dns-client I still can ping servers in the internet via it's IP address.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ALC6 Laptop with an installed instance of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with all updates. Because the laptop has no Ethernet adapter, I've connected  a Ethernet adapter via USB. Even without the Ethernet adapter just using WLAN, I have the same issue.

Note: Some hardware information removed because of max size of body size.

##Update## Hardware Information removed because massive lack of needed space (30k chars for this post). If you need hardware information, please let me know how to gain just the specific data you need.

I even don't know how to start troubleshooting or searching the internet for hints to whats going wrong. As you can imagine, the current situation is frustrating.

If you have any hints for me how to resolve the issue, it would be appreciated :)

Greetings, Ronny

##Update##
Not running:

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-10-26 06:32:43 CEST; 12h ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 561 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 11691)
     Memory: 9.2M
        CPU: 13.201s
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─561 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Okt 26 06:32:45 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: enx00e04c692628: Bus client set search domain list to: fritz.box
Okt 26 06:32:45 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: enx00e04c692628: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Okt 26 06:32:45 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: enx00e04c692628: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.178.67
Okt 26 06:32:47 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: enx00e04c692628: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.178.67, 2a02:908:d96:d660:402a:7fa5:de68:2dfc
Okt 26 06:32:49 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: wlp1s0: Bus client set search domain list to: fritz.box
Okt 26 06:32:49 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: wlp1s0: Bus client set default route setting: yes
Okt 26 06:32:49 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: wlp1s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.178.67
Okt 26 06:32:51 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: wlp1s0: Bus client set DNS server list to: 192.168.178.67, 2a02:908:d96:d660:402a:7fa5:de68:2dfc
Okt 26 08:20:56 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 192.168.178.67.
Okt 26 11:53:45 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[561]: Grace period over, resuming full feature set (UDP+EDNS0) for DNS server 192.168.178.67.
```

Not running:

```
ronald@ronaldIdeaPad3:~$ sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-10-26 19:13:35 CEST; 14min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 25991 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 11691)
     Memory: 4.6M
        CPU: 1.124s
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─25991 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.a>
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Using system hostname 'ronaldIdeaPad3'.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

Just restarted:

```
ronald@ronaldIdeaPad3:~$ 
ronald@ronaldIdeaPad3:~$ sudo systemctl restart  systemd-resolved
ronald@ronaldIdeaPad3:~$ sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-10-26 19:13:35 CEST; 9s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 25991 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 11691)
     Memory: 4.6M
        CPU: 96ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─25991 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.a>
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Using system hostname 'ronaldIdeaPad3'.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

edit3: journalctl -u systemd-resolved

```
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Consumed 13.227s CPU time.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.a>
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[25991]: Using system hostname 'ronaldIdeaPad3'.
Okt 26 19:13:35 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Consumed 1.219s CPU time.
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[26234]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[26234]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Okt 26 19:28:25 ronaldIdeaPad3 systemd-resolved[26234]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.a>
lines 1428-1481/1483 100%
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `systemctl status system-resolved` when it "dies". Because this will show service status, as well as the last 10 log lines.

Comment: i needed to remove the hardware information, but here it is. The service seems to running, but every try to make a nslookup results in an error. Other devices run flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Update (for the case someone else had/has the problem): After a short while and the regular installation of updates (apt-get update, apt-get upgrade), the described effect in this question happens only sometimes and now nearly never.

I believe, it was a problem with the Network Manager, which was patched somewhere in the past.

Because i didn't found any hints for this thesis, i cannot say without anny doubt this was the cause for my problems.